# Downloading files from box.com using content api, GZIP

Tags: box

I have a 6mb txt file in Box.com site.
Now i would like to download the file using api. as it takes time to download, i would like to download it as a gzipped file. 
As given here https://developers.box.com/docs/ where we have to add accept-encoding header with the values "gzip, deflate". I have added this header but the file is not downloaded as zip file it has the same size as 6mb, if it is zipped then it should be less than one mb in size.

But it is not happening. The following are the headers passed in REST request.

```
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)                      Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36
Authorization: Bearer ACCESSTOKEN
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,te;q=0.6
```

The following are the response headers.

```
Server: nginx 
Date: Thu, 24 Jul 2014 16:24:56 GMT 
Content-Type: application/octet-stream 
Content-Length: 6685772 
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-control: private
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="abc.log";filename*=UTF-8''  
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

Is there anything that I missed here?

Answer (score 1):

I have run into the same problem. However, I have also realized why this may be happening. Quoting  the [Box SDK documentation](http://developers.box.com/docs/):

> If the file is available to be downloaded, the response will be a 302
>   Found to a URL at dl.boxcloud.com. The dl.boxcloud.com URL is not
>   persistent. Clients will need to follow the redirect in order to
>   actually download the file. The raw data of the file is returned
>   unless the file ID is invalid or the user does not have access to it.

The important point to note is that there is a client redirect to a non-persistent URL in order to download the file. When we check the sequence of headers that are passed as a part of the redirect request, you can see that the **Accept-Encoding: gzip deflate** is missing. I used Fiddler to try this out, you can use any other HTTP proxy or interceptor.

This should be the reason why the files are not getting downloaded using the **gzip** encoding.

Hope this helps.